# XOR Multi Layer Perceptron outputting "none" as final result?

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm not sure if everything is define properly or not, but for some reason I can't make it stop printing "None" instead of actual values as the final output.
I even tried using Relu function instead of sigmoid but that was just a wild guess. Other than that, the code seemed pretty straight forward

```
#imports
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
#Variables
hidden_layer1_node= 2
hidden_layer2_node= 1
output = 1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[4,2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[4,1])
#neural model
def neural_model():
    #2 input by 2 neuron, 2 bias for two neuron
    layer1_weight = {'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,hidden_layer1_node])),
                'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_layer1_node]))}
    #2 input by 1 neuron, 1 bias for 1 neuron
    layer2_weight = {'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,hidden_layer2_node])),
                'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_layer2_node]))}

    #z value for first layer
    zl1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,layer1_weight['weight']), layer1_weight['bias'])
    #prediction for first layer
    prediction1 = tf.sigmoid(zl1)

    #z value for second layer
    zl2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(zl1,layer2_weight['weight']), layer2_weight['bias'])
    #prediction for first layer
    prediction2 = tf.sigmoid(zl2)

    return prediction2;


#cost function
def cost_function():
    prediction = neural_model()
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    return loss

#Optimization
loss = cost_function()
training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

#training stage
train_x = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
train_y = [[0],[1],[1],[0]]

initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#forward feed + back prop 4 times
epoch = 4

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #init all tf variable
    sess.run(initialize)

    for i in range(epoch):
        for _ in range(5000):
            c = sess.run(training, feed_dict={x:train_x,y:train_y})

        print(c)    

#Output
#None
#None
#None
#None
```

Comment: Please do not post code in the form of images. It makes copy-paste difficult and makes your content inaccessible to users that may require a screen reader or other similar assistive technology due to disability. Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't want to click your links. Please include everything in the post, preferably as a [mcve]. The lesser the clicks, the better.

Comment: I apologize for the links the lead you to images. You're right that must be annoying. But any help I can get from you guys will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I'm printing out c which I should not. I should be printing the actual value of the cost. However now I noticed that the network do not train as the cost or in this case the loss function actually remain the same through epochs... is anyone still looking at this lol

Answer (score 0):

```
#def neural_model():
    layer1_weight = {'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,hidden_layer1_node])),
                'bias':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layer1_node]))}

    layer2_weight = {'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,hidden_layer2_node])),
                'bias':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layer2_node]))}


    zl1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,layer1_weight['weight']), layer1_weight['bias'])
    prediction1 = tf.sigmoid(zl1)

    zl2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(prediction1,layer2_weight['weight']), layer2_weight['bias'])
    return tf.sigmoid(zl2)

prediction = neural_model()

#cost function
def cost_function():
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(-1*((y*tf.log(prediction))+((1-y)*tf.log(1.0-prediction))))
    return loss

#Optimization
loss = cost_function()
training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

#training stage
train_x = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
train_y = [[0],[1],[1],[0]]

initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()
epoch = 4

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(epoch):
        for _ in range(5000):
            sess.run(training, feed_dict={x:train_x,y:train_y})

        print(sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x:train_x,y:train_y}))

    print(sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x:train_x,y:train_y}))
```

Comment: The Major changes: 1- I'm not too sure about this but it seems like the cost function was very low from the start and for some reason the cross entropy function that TensorFlow provide doesn't seem to do the job with such small data. 2- The gradient descent  had a learning rate of 0.05. I find that 0.1 is more optimal for just 4 epoch else it doesn't learn fast enough. One could simply use 0.05 as a learning rate and increase the number of epoch and iterations.3- I was trying to print the session of training which should be the session of loss!!!!